# What's the most efficient way to pass a string from a Win32 app to a PowerShell script?

Tags: c++, powershell, winapi

I am coding a native Win32 app that will be called from a PowerShell script. It needs to pass the result back to the PowerShell script in a form of a string (so it's not just an integer.)

What is the most efficient way to do that?

Comment: Are you looking for "any" way or for "only an efficient" way?

Comment: Use UTF16-LE ("Unicode" in Windows lingo) consistently and you won't have any problems

Comment: @user12002570 ok, at this point seeing the dearth of responses, I'd be fine with any way. All I can think of is saving it somewhere in a file system or in a registry. But that falls apart in case of simultaneous inquiries.

Comment: Pipes are probably the way to go. This is assuming that PowerShell can P/Invoke the respective platform services to create pipes, and wait on kernel objects.

Comment: Not a direct answer but you could write a custom cmdlet (using .NET 4.8 which is already deployed on Windows) and that could call your exe or some dll using interop. That's not hard and from there you're really integrated into PowerShell host. This way you'd propose a "real" PowerShell interface to the world and also avoid most console woes.

Comment: @IInspectable of that's a good idea. I can make a native Win32 DLL and have the PowerShell pinvoke into it. Then it can use the input parameters as a string buffer that the DLL will fill in. That could be even faster than the pipe IPC, don't you think? I just wonder how easy is it to pinvoke from the PS?

Comment: That could be an option, though you should verify the following: `1` Does the DLL get mapped into PowerShell's address space? `2` Can you allocate (and pin!) a memory buffer from PowerShell? If the latter cannot be done, you may wish to consider a mixed-mode assembly using C++/CLI. This allows you to write native C++ code and expose a managed interface. I don't know how easy (or whether at all) it is to consume a mixed-mode assembly from PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the helpful comments:

- An ***out-of-process* solution** is **simplest, but not efficient**:

  - Create your application as a *console*-subsystem application and make it output the string via its *stdout stream*.

    - As any shell, PowerShell can invoke your application directly and capture its output (e.g., `$output = .\yourapp.exe ...`)
  - PowerShell decodes such a string based on the encoding stored in [`Console.OutputEncoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Console.OutputEncoding), which defaults to the system's legacy OEM code page.

    - This limits what characters can be encoded, and requires transcoding into native .NET strings (which are composed of UTF-16 code units).
    - However, you're free to emit UTF-16LE strings, as long as the calling PowerShell script (temporarily) sets `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode`; ditto for UTF-8 (`[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()`).

      - While UTF-16LE allows for the most direct decoding into .NET strings, I doubt the performance difference matters in practice, especially in the context of PowerShell scripts.
      - Nowadays it is possible to configure a system to use UTF-8 *system-wide* (which sets both the ANSI and the OEM code page to `65001`, i.e. UTF-8), but note that this has *far-reaching consequences* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) for details.
- ***In-process* solutions** are **more efficient**:

  - The **best option** is to **create a .NET assembly via [C++/CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-programming-with-cpp-cli-visual-cpp)**, as [IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable) suggests:

    - PowerShell can consume .NET assemblies *directly*.
  - Alternatively, you can create a **native DLL** that **must be called via [P/Invoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services)**:

    - PowerShell supports P/Invoke calls only *indirectly* via *ad-hoc compilation of C# code* using its [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type) cmdlet.

      - Such **ad-hoc compilation** incurs a ***once-per-session* performance penalty**.
  - The **PowerShell example below** shows how to use a P/Invoke to call a native library, specifically a WinAPI (Windows API) function:

    - It calls the Unicode version of the [`GetWindowText`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtextw) function, with the PowerShell process' own console window handle, in order to retrieve the latter's title.
    - Note how a [`System.Text.StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.StringBuilder) instance must be used to provide a preallocated buffer to the native function's `LPWSTR`-typed parameter, into which the native function copies a UTF-16 string.

      - .NET takes care of pinning and unpinning the memory, and converting the buffer to a native .NET string that can be retrieved by calling `.ToString()` on the `StringBuilder` instance afterwards.
      - Note how the `sb.Capacity` value is passed  *with `+1`*, given that native functions usually expect the character account *including the terminating `NUL` character*, which .NET manages automatically behind the scenes.

```bash
Add-Type -Namespace SampleNS -Name Sample -UsingNamespace System.Text -MemberDefinition @'
    
    // P/Invoke declaration
    // Note the use of `CharSet=CharSet.Unicode` to ensure 
    // that the *Unicode* version is called.
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder stringBuf, int nMaxCount);
    
    // Convenience function that wraps the StringBuilder logic
    public static string GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd) {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(1024); // Preallocate the buffer.
        GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity+1);
        return sb.ToString();
    }

'@

# Invoke with the current PowerShell window's handle.
[SampleNS.Sample]::GetWindowText(
    (Get-Process -Id $PID).MainWindowHandle
)
```